# How to unlock table in sybase?

Tags: sql, sybase, database-administration, sqlanywhere, unlock

im trying to change some types on my table in sybase, but when i change it, the output is this one.

> User 'DBA' has the row in 'table' locked

How to unlock this?

Comment: Well, someone has an open session on that table.  Kick everyone off.

Comment: What Sybase database are you using?

Comment: im using sybase central, sql anywhere 16! i tryed to make the change, disconnect the server and connect again and it worked, but not always :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would:

1. determine the connection_id  using sa_locks (documentation [here](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbreference/sa-locks-system-procedure.html))
2. issue the [drop connection](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbreference/drop-connection-statement.html) *connection_id* statement to the connection that is causing the lock to the table.

Use it with care!

Comment: Hi @Teodor. Could you please tell me what causes this locks and what the drop connection do? Is this dangerous?

Comment: You will have to do some reading http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbusage/tranlock.html. It would give you more information than I can in 400 characters.