# sql exception: " Sql anywhere error: <user> has the row in <tablename> locked"?

Tags: sql, swing, sybase, sqlanywhere

sql exception: " Sql anywhere error:  has the row in  locked" ? I have also used commit/rollback in the end of every procedure where  is used. I have to restart the server everytime to release the locks.

Comment: check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413676/how-to-unlock-table-in-sybase

Comment: and this http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbusage/tranlock.html