# Sqoop export from HDFS dir to sybase IQ failed

Tags: sybase, sqoop

I am trying to export HDFS file from a HDFS directory to sybase IQ table.

I have placed the sybase driver in sqoop lib path correctly .

**sqoop Command :**

```
sqoop export  \
 --connect jdbc:sybase:Tds:sybasehost:port/DATABASE=OMEGA \
 --username dummy \
 --password dummy \
 --driver com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver \
 --table omega_sybase_table \
 --export-dir /user/cloudera/omega/output_files/ \
 --input-fields-terminated-by ','
```

I am getting the below error and this export failed.

```
17/04/25 16:17:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1489579695153_4935_m_000002_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check failed map task logs
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.sql.SQLException: SQL Anywhere Error -210: User 'another user' has the row in 'omega_sybase_table' locked
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.write(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:233)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.write(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:46)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:658)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:84)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: SQL Anywhere Error -210: User 'another user' has the row in 'omega_sybase_table' locked
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.getAllExceptions(Unknown Source)
```

Could someone help me fixing this issue?

Comment: `User 'another user' has the row in 'omega_sybase_table' locked` , error is pretty evident, no?

Comment: Yes. I am very new to Sybase .What needs to done to fix this? How do I unlock this Sybase table?

Comment: Refer this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21461090/7303447

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its getting because of multiple mappers tasks being used in sqoop export command.

Sybase IQ only allows one connection at a time, multiple mappers tasks try to insert records in sybase iq table in parallel.

Solution is to use -m 1 in sqoop export command.

Comment: Just to confirm that only one mapper (or one IQ connection) can be used to import from Hive to IQ?  This just surprised me.